# Question- How to read the CFA results using the ordered statement in Lavaan package for ordinal data?

Tags: regression, r, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am using the `ordered` statement in my CFA model when running `lavaan` in R, but I couldn't figure out how to read the results. I am hoping to know (1) which indices I should report (standard or scaled?) and (2) any recommended references for result interpretation.

I'm running a CFA ($6$ factors, $35$ ordinal observed variables, $n=272$) using the `lavaan` library.

```
library(lavaan)

# six factor model
    model <- ' F1 =~ culture_6+ culture_7+ culture_8+ culture_9+ culture_15+ culture_16+ culture_17+ culture_18+ culture_19+ culture_21
               F2 =~ culture_1+ culture_2+ culture_3+ culture_4+ culture_5 
               F3 =~ culture_31+ culture_32+ culture_33+ culture_34+ culture_35
               F4 =~ culture_26+ culture_27+ culture_28+ culture_29+ culture_30
               F5 =~ culture_10+ culture_12+ culture_13+ culture_14
               F6 =~ culture_11+ culture_20+ culture_22+ culture_23+ culture_24+ culture_25  ' 

# ordered CFA

    fit_o <- cfa(model, data=dat, ordered=names(dat))
    summary(fit_o, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized = TRUE)


# Results
lavaan 0.6.16 ended normally after 113 iterations

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                       190

  Number of observations                           272

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                              2856.679    2485.105
  Degrees of freedom                               545         545
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.357
  Shift parameter                                          379.288
    simple second-order correction                                

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                            216272.524   31465.530
  Degrees of freedom                               595         595
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  6.987

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.989       0.937
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.988       0.931
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                            NA
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                               NA

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.125       0.115
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.121       0.110
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.130       0.119
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.000       0.000
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    1.000       1.000
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                                  NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                        NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                        NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                            NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                            NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.080       0.080

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                           Robust.sem
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model        Unstructured
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html), switching the argument `ordered = T` accomplishes the following in `lavaan`:

> When the `ordered=` argument is used, `lavaan` will automatically switch to the WLSMV estimator: it will use diagonally weighted least squares (DWLS) to estimate the model parameters, but it will use the full weight matrix to compute robust standard errors, and a mean- and variance-adjusted test statistic.

The scaled statistic by consequence applies a correction for the less precise estimates of the default estimation, so the scaled statistic should be used in this situation.